# persisting a session variable even after the user logs out in Drupal

Tags: drupal, session

I am currently working on a drupal project, where i need to keep one session variable set even after the user logs out. Or i can preserve it before session_destroy is called and then set it back, But dunno how and where drupal handles it.

How to make it possible? Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save out your variable when using [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) in drupal 6, or [hook_user_logout](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/7) in drupal 7.0.

Comment: hook_user can be used to save out the variable but how do i make it accesible after the user logs out.??